# How to present json values with html erb template as an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a simple request with httparty and i also want to display them as a list with the code below.

```
  def index
    reqd = HTTParty.get("https://api.dynadot.com/api3.xml?key=xxxxxx&command=search&domain0=mydomain.com&domain1=mydomain.net").body
    @results = Hash.from_xml(reqd)
  end
```

output is

```
{"Results"=>{"SearchResponse"=>[{"SearchHeader"=>{"SuccessCode"=>"0", 
    "DomainName"=>"mydomain.com", "Status"=>"success"}}, {"SearchHeader"=>{"SuccessCode"=>"0", 
    "DomainName"=>"mydomain.net", "Status"=>"success", "Available"=>"no"}}]}}
```

How do i use this such that i can have result in my index.html.erb to look like this

```
<% @results.each do |result| %>
    ##can call any value here like domain name, status etc
<% end %>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use jbuilder gem? Native functionality... If you don't, let me know so I answer on your terms...

Comment: Try `<% @results['SearchResponse'].each do |response| %>`

Comment: i dont want to represent it with json. i wnat to use normal html

Comment: @RubyRacer i am getting undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass

Comment: I didn't get you. You want to show the hash/array structure in html?

Comment: And Try `<% @results['Results']['SearchResponse'].each do |response| %>` instead

Comment: yes. just like the normal rails array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want, perhaps this will help:

```
@results = {"Results"=>{"SearchResponse"=>[{"SearchHeader"=>{"SuccessCode"=>"0",
    "DomainName"=>"mydomain.com", "Status"=>"success"}}, {"SearchHeader"=>{"SuccessCode"=>"0",
    "DomainName"=>"mydomain.net", "Status"=>"success", "Available"=>"no"}}]}}

@results["Results"]["SearchResponse"].map { |x| x["SearchHeader"] }.each do |s| 
  puts s["SuccessCode"]
  puts s["DomainName"] 
  puts s["Status"]
end
```

result:

```
mydomain.com
success
mydomain.net
success
```

Comment: This is what i get in return [{"SuccessCode"=>"0", "DomainName"=>"mydomain.com", "Status"=>"success", "Available"=>"no"}, {"SuccessCode"=>"0", "DomainName"=>"mydomain.net", "Status"=>"success", "Available"=>"no"}]

Comment: It feels like its almost getting there to be just like your result.

Comment: I meant that in `.each` block you can use your domains and statuses. If you want to get the array or something, thats another thing.

Comment: it works just as expected.` @results = @results["Results"]["SearchResponse"].map { |x| x["SearchHeader"] } <% @results.each do |x| %>
    <%= x["DomainName"] %> <%= x["Status"] %>`
<% end %>